# Creating a persistent Link to an EFS drive on a Windows EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I have created a Windows EC2 instance on AWS, and I have loaded it up with all of my needed software. My intention is to use this instance to create an image, so that I can (in the very near future) load up a much more powerful instance type using this image, and run a bunch of computations.

However, I also need to have a centralized location to store data. So, I created an EFS drive on AWS, and now I am trying to connect my instance to the EFS using a symbolic link that will persist to every other instance I load up in the future. I want to eventually have an army of instances, all of which use the centralized EFS drive as their primary storage device so that they can all load and save data, which can then be used by other instances.

I've been running Google searches all morning, but I'm coming up empty on how to do this. Any resources or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EFS is basically a managed NFS server.  In order to mount this to a Windows instance, you will need to find an NFS client for windows.

An alternative would be to mount the EFS to a linux-based instance, and export the file system using Samba which could then be mounted on your Windows instances.  Doing this you would lose out on a lot of the benefits of EFS (your linux instance is a single point of failure, and for high-bandwidth requirements will be a bottleneck) but it might be possible.

You don't say what you are trying to accomplish, but I would suggest designing a solution that would pull data from S3 as needed.  That would also allow you to run multiple instances in parallel.

Comment: Actually I did say what I'm trying to accomplish: "I want to eventually have an army of instances, all of which use the centralized EFS drive as their primary storage device so that they can all load and save data, which can then be used by other instances." The system I'm using already pulls data from s3 as needed, but I need a centralized storage solution that saves intermediary files along the way.

Comment: I would continue to read & write from S3, but look at coordinating it with SQS or SWF.  You may also want to look to see if AWS Batch can help.

Comment: @NathanCalverley you are coming up empty because *["Using Amazon EFS with Microsoft Windows Amazon EC2 instances is not supported."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html)*  It requires an NFS4.1 client, which the native Windows client isn't.  You need a third-party client to mount EFS directly onto Windows, or the Samba/Linux/EFS gateway Chris has described.